# Oracle Subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

**data in last 30 days**

```
user age value 
a    14   42
b    12   43
c    34   54
d    31   45
```

**data in last 20 days**

```
user age value 
a    14   23
b    12   45
c    34   12
d    31   14
```

**data in last 10 days**

```
user age value 
b    12   4
c    34   5
d    31   4
```

**Expected Result**

```
u1 a1   v1  v2  v3
a  14   42  23   -
b  12   43  45   4
c  34   54  12   5
d  31   45  14   4
```

**but result i am getting**

```
u1 a1   v1  v2  v3
b  12   43  45   4
c  34   54  12   5
d  31   45  14   4
```

**Query i used**

```
WITH q1 AS
  (SELECT name u1,
    age a1,
    coalcase ( to_char(v_count),'-')
  FROM USER
  WHERE ord_date BETWEEN sysdate - 30 AND sysdate
  ),
  q2 AS
  (SELECT name u2,
    age a2,
    coalcase ( to_char(v_count),'-')
  FROM USER
  WHERE ord_date BETWEEN sysdate - 20 AND sysdate
  ),
  q3 AS (
  (SELECT name u3,
    age a2,
    coalcase ( to_char(v_count),'-')
  FROM USER
  WHERE ord_date BETWEEN sysdate - 10 AND sysdate )
SELECT u1,
  a1,
  v1,
  v2,
  v3
FROM q1,
  q1,
  q3
WHERE q1.u1=q2.u2
AND q2.u2  =q3.u2
AND q3.u3  =q1.u1;
```

Since the user doesn't have any entry for last 10 days the data is not coming as expected.

Can anyone help me how to get that as well as expected

Comment: try `left join`. And this will not work if primary table does not return all four rows. you need to update your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT U1.NAME      U1,
       U1.AGE       A1,
       U1.V_COUNT   AS V1,
       COALCASE(TO_CHAR(U2.V_COUNT),'-') AS V2,
       COALCASE(TO_CHAR(U3.V_COUNT),'-') AS V3
  FROM USER   U1
  LEFT JOIN USER   U2 ON U1.NAME = U2.NAME AND U2.ORD_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE
  LEFT JOIN USER   U3 ON U1.NAME = U3.NAME AND U3.ORD_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE
 WHERE U1.ORD_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    name,
    age,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN ord_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
                      THEN TO_CHAR(v_count) END), '-') AS v_last_30,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN ord_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE
                      THEN TO_CHAR(v_count) END), '-') AS v_last_20,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN ord_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE
                      THEN TO_CHAR(v_count) END), '-') AS v_last_10
FROM USER
WHERE
    ord_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY
    name,
    age;
```

The idea here is to aggregate by user (and age), and then selectively choose the correct value based on the `ord_date`.

Comment: It worked , as well left join also worked , But i chose to go with left join since its giving me exact result what i need have really, Thanks Lots